# Can I tell Inno Setup *not* to create unins000 files

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

I'm using Inno Setup to package a third-party installer with another EXE I built to prep our firm environment for the install.  I'd really like to delete all the installer files from the end user's computer after I'm finished.  I tried using `deleteafterinstall` on the temporary directory I create with Inno, but it doesn't work.  Inno automatically creates `unins000.exe` and `unins000.dat` in the installation directory.  So when it tries to delete the root directory, it finds that it it's not empty.

I don't need Inno's uninstaller, as the 3P app has its own.  Can I tell Inno Setup **not** to create the unins000 files?  Or can I tell it to delete the temporary directory even if it's not empty?

Comment: Typically you should extract temporary files to `{tmp}`.  Inno will automatically clean this up once the installation completes.  This is the only place where a recursive structure (subfolders) can be cleaned up properly from.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `Uninstallable` directive to stop the creation of the uninstall files.

```
[Setup]
Uninstallable=no
```

I still can't get it to delete the temp directory it creates, though.

Comment: That temp directory you'll never get off since installer unpack the needed files to run.

Comment: With "Uninstallable = no", you cannot uninstall your app from Control Panel...